# Optimizing Dijkstra on grid Python (Microsoft Interview)

Tags: performance, algorithm, python-3.x, time-limit-exceeded, graph

Given a square grid of size N, each cell of which contains integer cost which represents a cost to traverse through that cell, we need to find a path from top left cell to bottom right cell by which the total cost incurred is minimum.
From the cell (i,j) we can go (i,j-1), (i, j+1), (i-1, j), (i+1, j).

Note: It is assumed that negative cost cycles do not exist in the input matrix.

```
Example 1:

Input: grid = {{9,4,9,9},{6,7,6,4},
{8,3,3,7},{7,4,9,10}}
Output: 43
Explanation: The grid is-
9 4 9 9
6 7 6 4
8 3 3 7
7 4 9 10
The minimum cost is-
9 + 4 + 7 + 3 + 3 + 7 + 10 = 43.
```

**My working code:**

```
global INT_MAX

# value of n is passed by the driver along with the grid
INT_MAX = 3 ** 38

class Solution:
    
    # <- this returns the minVertex's co-orinates ->
    def minimumVertex(self,distMat,visited):
        minVertexi = 0
        minVertexj = 0
        max1 = INT_MAX
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                if distMat[i][j] < max1 and visited[i][j] == False:
                    max1 =  distMat[i][j]
                    minVertexi = i
                    minVertexj = j
        return minVertexi, minVertexj
            
    def minimumCostPath(self, grid):
        
        # <- visited matrix is created with all False ->
        visited = []
        for i in range(n):
            eachRow = []
            for j in range(n):
                eachRow.append(False)
            visited.append(eachRow)
        # <- distMat is created with all values initialized with INT_MAX ->    
        distMat = []
        for i in range(n):
            eachRow1 = []
            for j in range(n):
                eachRow1.append(INT_MAX)
            distMat.append(eachRow1)
        distMat[0][0] = grid[0][0]

        drow = [-1, 1, 0, 0]
        dcol = [0, 0, -1, 1]

        
        for _ in range(n):
            for currj in range(n):
                mini,minj = self.minimumVertex(distMat,visited)
            
                visited[mini][minj] = True
                for k in range(len(drow)):
                    nbri = mini + drow[k]
                    nbrj = minj + dcol[k]
                    # print("outside nbri = ",nbri,"outside nbrj = ",nbrj)
                    if nbri >=0 and nbrj >= 0 and nbri < n and nbrj < n:
                        if visited[nbri][nbrj] == False:
                            # print("inside nbri = ",nbri,"inside nbrj = ",nbrj)

                            if distMat[nbri][nbrj] >  distMat[mini][minj] + grid[nbri][nbrj]:
                                distMat[nbri][nbrj] = distMat[mini][minj] + grid[nbri][nbrj]
        return distMat[n-1][n-1]
```

**Expected Time Compelxity:** O(n2*log(n))

**Expected Auxiliary Space:** O(n2)

**Problem with my code:**

My logic is alright however it is exceeding the time limit, how do I optimize it?

**NOTE:** The grid is always a square grid and N (dimension) is passed to the function along with the grid. I took N = 4 here because I was debugging the code for a single test case.

Comment: I believe this solution is O(n^4).  `minimumVertex()` is O(n^2) and it is called n^2 times in the nested loops in `minimumCostPath()`. Try using a heap to keep track of the minimum vertex.

Answer (score 1):

### Actual time complexity

As you correctly state, the *expected* time complexity of Dijkstra's on a square matrix is `O(n^2 log n)`. However, your algorithm has a complexity of at least `O(n^4)` due to the way you locate the minimum vertex.

```
for _ in range(n):
    for currj in range(n):
        # <--- executed n^2 times here
        mini,minj = self.minimumVertex(distMat,visited)
        ...

def minimumVertex(self,distMat,visited):
    minVertexi = 0
    minVertexj = 0
    max1 = INT_MAX
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            # <--- takes n^2 time
            ...
```

In fact, the algorithm you implemented isn't purely Dijkstra's, but a blend of [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstras_algorithm) and [Floyd's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm).
You should read through the links above, particularly the *Pseudocode* sections to understand how each of the algorithms works, and the parts that you're mixing up.

### Dijkstra's algorithm

The key data structure which allows Dijkstra's algorithm to work in `O(n^2 log n)` time is a [**priority queue**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) which allows you to insert elements and remove the top element in `O(log n)` time.
This data structure is commonly implemented using a [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap), and has a standard implementation in Python as the [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) library.

You should adapt your code to use this data structure instead of the distance table as shown below.
It is important that the **first** field of the tuple is the distance, since this determines the sorting.

```
def minimumCostPath(self, grid):
    # definitions of n, visited, drow, dcol

    queue = [(grid[0][0], 0, 0)]
    while queue:
        dist, i, j = heapq.heappop(queue)

        if visited[i][j]:
            continue
        visited[i][j] = True
        
        if i == j == n - 1:
            return dist

        for k in range(len(drow)):
            ni = i + drow[k]
            nj = j + dcol[k]
            if 0 <= ni < n and 0 <= nj < n:
                heapq.heappush(queue, (dist + grid[ni][nj], ni, nj))

    assert False, "queue is exhausted but we haven't reached the destination yet"
```

### Benchmarking surprise

After writing all of this, I decided to quantify the improvement by benchmarking.
This is the code I used to see how my implementation compares against the original.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import time
    N = 100
    grid = [[j for _ in range(N)] for j in range(N)]
    solver = Solution()

    start = time.time()
    print(solver.minimumCostPath(grid))
    end = time.time()
    print(f"Solved grid with size {N} in {1000*(end - start):.3f}ms")
```

To my surprise, your version was *actually faster*, but more importantly it gave **incorrect** results.

> My logic is alright

No, it's not.
The issue is the usage of `n` in the `minimumVertex` function. Because you define `n = 4` as a global, this value is used instead of the actual size of the grid. This makes your algorithm appear fast, but actually be incorrect for `n > 4`.

### Conclusion

As it turns out, while the algorithm you (I imagine) intended to implement is `O(n^4)`, your code was actually `O(n^2)` all along. If this really resulted in TLE, Python is not going to be able to handle this question.
What I find much more likely is that your code failed due to an incorrect response - using the correct implementation of Dijkstra's above is likely to fix this.

Comment: This code was meant for an online judge and the reason I defined n = 4 because I was debugging the code for a single test case where N was 4. Now understand this, the grid is always a square grid (rows = columns) and the driver calls my function with the grid and N so that's really not an issue here, I hope you are getting what I am trying to say.

Comment: Also, no offence but refrain from saying the logic is wrong and try asking the OP or thinking the reason behind something.

Comment: @ShubhamPrashar Next time please include the whole code in the question. In `minimumCostPath` you calculate the correct n from the given grid, but the proceed to use a *different* n in `minimumVertex`. With the snippet provided there is no reasonable explanation other than a logic error. In fact, even if you define the global n to be the size of the grid, I would still consider this a logic error - you should either use the global n in both functions, or the calculated n in both functions.

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree with you here but what do you think about the complexity part? Everythings fine yet getting the TLE. How to optimize it?

Comment: @ShubhamPrashar Re-read the first two sections of my answer, where I show that the complexity of your solution is actually `O(n^4)`. You should use [a correct implementation of Dijkstra's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstras_algorithm#Using_a_priority_queue), which will give you the desired complexity of `O(n^2 log n)`.

Comment: `your code was actually O(n^2)` and what about this?

Comment: @ShubhamPrashar The code you *sent* was `O(n^2)` because of the global constant `n = 4`. If in the actual code you define the global correctly, the complexity will be `O(n^4)`. I'll edit the question later to make this more clear.

Comment: Alright got it now. Thanks!